# Is grounding of the LRS-100-24 power supply 100% needed?

Tags: power-supply

I'm trying to build a speaker for home but don't have basically any experience with electronics (i can do some basic soldering).

I went to a local electronics shop and asked the seller what product would i need to get it working (i already have a small 2x50w amp from ebay and speakers). So the man in the shop recommended i use this LRS-100-24 AC to DC power supply. [image]

He also gave me a wire that goes in the wall and into the power supply. The wire has 2 wires in it. As i understand if there would be three of them one would be for the ground. I would like to put the power supply in the speaker box. Would it be dangerous to not ground it?

The man in the store also told me i would need put 2 wires in -V and +V to harvest the full power from it. Is it true and can i just connect the two wires into one?

I will have to solder the wires from the power supply to a male DC jack(connector?), it has one longer piece of metal and a shorter one to connect wires to. Which one's + and -?

I hope i gave enough information. Please correct any grammar mistakes if there are any and thanks in advance.

Comment: What you have is a Class I power supply which is only rated and intended for a grounded mains connection. If you don’t ground it, for example using your two-conductor wire, you are compromising a lot of the safety and radio disturbance, but in all fairness, it will still work. Get yourself a proper 3 conductor wire and hook it up as indended. Next question will be if your audio amplifier can operate from a single simply like the one you have?

Comment: Well the amp is 2x50w 8-24v and my speakers are 4omhs max 50w.

Comment: If single supply, then no problem except for grounded wire.

Comment: Okay so ill go back and see if i can get a wire(whats that big wire called with the smaller wires) that has 3 wires and then i should be good?

Comment: You should ask the man in the store.  EE.SE isn't his volunteer application support.

Comment: Ok will do that.What do you mean under "EE.SE"?

Comment: EE.SE is a shorthand for "Electrical Engineering StackExchange", which is the title of this site.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, any metal cased equipment should be grounded to prevent a malfunction from putting line voltage on the case. The ground wire is not there for functionality, only for safety.

As to your second question regarding the V- and V+ - you only need to use one V- and one V+ connection, all four do not need to be used.

Most plug in DC connectors/jacks have the negative wire on the outside and the positive is the center pin.

Answer (score 0):

The power supply does not have a [Class 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appliance_classes#Class_II) logo on the sticker:

> A Class II or double insulated electrical appliance is one which has been designed in such a way that it does not require a safety connection to electrical earth (ground).

...and it has an Earth terminal, so it is [Class 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appliance_classes#Class_I).

Thus you need a power cord with an Earth wire.

Since you probably have tons of [IEC cords](https://www.google.fr/search?q=iec%20cord&safe=off&client=opera&hs=7GI&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiS2vaYpo3aAhWPPFAKHXW4BeAQ_AUICigB&biw=1277&bih=746) stashed somewhere (I got about a cubic foot of those in a box), just add an [IEC socket](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/iec-connectors/0426468/) to your enclosure, or grab a cord from your stash, cut it, and use it.

> The man in the store also told me i would need put 2 wires in -V and +V to harvest the full power from it. Is it true and can i just connect the two wires into one?

No, one wire is enough for your current. I think the manufacturer added another terminal for convenience. Don't use flimsy wire, lamp cord is fine, 1 mm2 or more.

> I will have to solder the wires from the power supply to a male DC jack(connector?), it has one longer piece of metal and a shorter one to connect wires to. Which one's + and -?

Usually + is in the center of the barrel connector, but please check the documentation of your amplifier... you never know...